# Heroku Error: Webpacker can't find application in /app/public/packs/manifest.json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpacker

I am trying to deploy my first heroku app but I keep getting the same Error in my Heroku logs

```
2023-04-20T14:39:37.948720+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2023-04-20T14:39:37.948693 #2] FATAL -- : [89c8c2cd-2e12-4dac-b4d1-1982bbba2b0f]
2023-04-20T14:39:37.948720+00:00 app[web.1]: [89c8c2cd-2e12-4dac-b4d1-1982bbba2b0f] ActionView::Template::Error (Webpacker can't find application in /app/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
2023-04-20T14:39:37.948721+00:00 app[web.1]: 1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
2023-04-20T14:39:37.948722+00:00 app[web.1]: unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2023-04-20T14:39:37.948723+00:00 app[web.1]: 2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
2023-04-20T14:39:37.948723+00:00 app[web.1]: 3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
2023-04-20T14:39:37.948724+00:00 app[web.1]: 4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
2023-04-20T14:39:37.948725+00:00 app[web.1]: Your manifest contains:
2023-04-20T14:39:37.948726+00:00 app[web.1]: {
2023-04-20T14:39:37.948726+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2023-04-20T14:39:37.948727+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2023-04-20T14:39:37.948727+00:00 app[web.1]: [89c8c2cd-2e12-4dac-b4d1-1982bbba2b0f]     12:     <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.8.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
2023-04-20T14:39:37.948727+00:00 app[web.1]: [89c8c2cd-2e12-4dac-b4d1-1982bbba2b0f]     13:     <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.8.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
2023-04-20T14:39:37.948728+00:00 app[web.1]: [89c8c2cd-2e12-4dac-b4d1-1982bbba2b0f]     14:
2023-04-20T14:39:37.948728+00:00 app[web.1]: [89c8c2cd-2e12-4dac-b4d1-1982bbba2b0f]     15:     <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload', defer: true %>
2023-04-20T14:39:37.948729+00:00 app[web.1]: [89c8c2cd-2e12-4dac-b4d1-1982bbba2b0f]     16:     <%= javascript_include_tag "activestorage" %>
2023-04-20T14:39:37.948730+00:00 app[web.1]: [89c8c2cd-2e12-4dac-b4d1-1982bbba2b0f]     17:   </head>
2023-04-20T14:39:37.948730+00:00 app[web.1]: [89c8c2cd-2e12-4dac-b4d1-1982bbba2b0f]     18:
2023-04-20T14:39:37.948730+00:00 app[web.1]: [89c8c2cd-2e12-4dac-b4d1-1982bbba2b0f]
2023-04-20T14:39:37.948730+00:00 app[web.1]: [89c8c2cd-2e12-4dac-b4d1-1982bbba2b0f] app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:15
```

If anyone knows hot to fix this Problem I would be very thankful because I have been trying to solve it on my own for the past days

Here is my git hub repository :

https://github.com/Jonasstannowski/Verso_Sud_Corato_project

I already checked my package.json file and reinstalled yarn and webpacker. This still didn't fix the Error.